# How to emit event end on process.stdin nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i have this simple part of code

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.trim().split('\n').map(str => str.trim());

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}

/*
 * Complete the simpleArraySum function below.
 */
function simpleArraySum(ar) {
    console.log(ar);

}

function main() {
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(process.env.OUTPUT_PATH);

    const arCount = parseInt(readLine(), 10);

    const ar = readLine().split(' ').map(arTemp => parseInt(arTemp, 10));

    let result = simpleArraySum(ar);

    ws.write(result + "\n");

    ws.end();
}
```

and i want to test in in console but i don't know how to send that i finished typing and now i want my program to operate. Can you tell me how to do it? (CTRL + D doesn't work)

[image]
I'm entering new inputs and it neverd ends... how to fix it?

this is how it works in terminal (or doesn't work)
[image]

Thanks in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: First, make sure that node js is properly installed (and if you want to access it from your command prompt ensure that it is stored as an environment variable which you can find how to do here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/r-enterprise/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0) Then open command prompt and head to the directory your file is stored and run `node yourfilename.js` and it should work.

Comment: Yea i know but here is problem. I know how to on my node.js program.. Imagine my program as 2 parts: input and output. My problem is: i dont know how to exit this first part (inputing part).

Comment: What do you mean by "CTRL + D doesn't work"? I've just run your code and Ctrl + D worked

Comment: Try running it in the actual terminal instead of the IDE built-in terminal. There may be issues because of that

Comment: I've edited my post.. This is the result of running it in terminal